# How to hide the gallery item if image url return 404 in reactjs?

Tags: image, reactjs, url

Here, I am creating the gallery using a loop and some of the image is not loaded due to 404 error. so I have to hide the element. Image is inside a div wrapper. So the issue is an error get the parent and then hide the element.

```
   <div class="pswp-thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="https:xxxxxxx/uploads/daily_uploads/resize/1506406936_67656_2_8.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
onErrorImage(e) {
  console.log(e.target.parentNode);
  e.target.parentNode.style.display="none";
}
```

image element

```
return (
    <img className="img-responsive" src={item.thumbnail} onError=
    {this.onErrorImage.bind(this)} />
);
```